# How to install wsp file in sharepoint2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have already tried based on the following site http://jaxsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/06/deploying-wsp-to-sharepoint-2013.html but I can't see anything on Manage Farm Solution other than a02.contenttypes.wsp this file... so, I don't know where the problem  i did. or Is there any new method to install wsp file on sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

This row from your link adds the WSP to "Manage Farm Solutions" page (if it is not sandboxed off course)

```
Add-SPSolution "c:\Deploy\WSP\{file name}.wsp"
```